# torch-scatter install failed: Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1

Tags: python, subprocess, python-wheel, torch-scatter

I am trying to install: `pip install torch-scatter==2.1.1` and got the following error:

```
Collecting torch-scatter==2.1.1
  Using cached torch_scatter-2.1.1.tar.gz (107 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
```

```
\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hgzk7elh\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

The torch 2.1.2 is properly installed and I can see it by `pip list`.
The pip is updated (23.3.2).
The setuptools is updated (69.0.3) by `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall setuptools`.
I also tried: `pip install torch-scatter==2.1.1 -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-2.1.2+${cpu}.html` got the same error.

I am running on (.venv) in windows system.
Can anyone help me on issue? Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I'm having the same issue. Thanks!